# How to get raw accelerometer and Magnetometer data in Android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, magnetometer

I know that, for gyroscopes, there exist TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED, which provide raw gyro data.

Does anything similar exist for accelerpmeter and magnetometer, or they are by default raw data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accelerometer is raw by default.  For magnetometer, use TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED